# How to optimize null check in SQL?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server-2014

I have a procedure that gets me some data based on a date.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetLatestTicketsByDate]
    @Datemin datetime2,
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @LatestTickets TABLE
    (
        DomainId bigint, 
        SoldTickets bigint
    )

    INSERT INTO @LatestTickets(DomainId,SoldTickets)
        SELECT  
            DomainId, SoldTickets 
        FROM 
            DomainDetailDataHistory
        WHERE  
            [Date] >= @Datemin

    SELECT * FROM @LatestTickets
END
```

Now I want to make this procedure smarter by adding a new paramater to it BUT this paramater is optional.

My code looks like this:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetLatestTicketsByDate]
        @Datemin datetime2,
        @Id uniqueidentifier = NULL 
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @LatestTickets TABLE
        (
            DomainId bigint, 
            SoldTickets bigint
        )

        IF (@Id IS NULL)
        BEGIN 
            INSERT INTO @LatestTickets(DomainId,SoldTickets)
                SELECT DomainId, SoldTickets 
                FROM DomainDetailDataHistory
                WHERE [Date] >= @Datemin

            SELECT * FROM @LatestTickets
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN 
            INSERT INTO @LatestTickets(DomainId,SoldTickets)
                SELECT DomainId, SoldTickets 
                FROM DomainDetailDataHistory
                WHERE Id = @Id AND  [Date] >= @Datemin

            SELECT * FROM @LatestTickets
     END
END
```

This works but I don't like this structure and was wondering if there is a better way?

I tried this:

```
INSERT INTO @LatestTickets(DomainId,SoldTickets)
    SELECT DomainId, SoldTickets 
    FROM DomainDetailDataHistory
    WHERE (@Id IS NOT NULL AND Id = @Id) AND [Date] >= @Datemin

SELECT * FROM @LatestTickets
```

But it did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `@Id IS NULL OR Id = @Id`

```
INSERT INTO @LatestTickets(DomainId,SoldTickets)
SELECT  DomainId, SoldTickets
FROM DomainDetailDataHistory
WHERE (@Id IS NULL OR Id = @Id) AND  [Date] >= @Datemin
```

Comment: wow...Well i was on the right track. Im not even going to tell you how much time i put on this